# Checking that [1, null, 1] and [1, 1] are valid Binary Search Trees

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

What would be the possible Binary Search Tree  of `[1, null, 1]` and `[1, 1]`? Will there be any difference at all?

My code verifies `[1, 1]` as BST but not `[1, null, 1]`, and I don't understand why...

```c
bool isBST(TreeNode* root, int max, int min){
    if(!root)
        return true;
    if((max!= NULL && max<=root->val) || (min!= NULL && min>root->val))
        return false;
    if(!isBST(root->left, root->val, min) || !isBST(root->right, max, root->val))
        return false;
    return true;
}
bool isValidBST(TreeNode* root) {
    int min =NULL, max = NULL;
    return isBST(root, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Why does my code not return true for `[1, null, 1]`?

Comment: `if((max!= NULL && max<=root->val)` <<-- You are comparing an integer to a pointer (constant) here.

Comment: What does `[1,null,1]` mean exactly? Besides the fact that it isn't a tree, you also seem to be confusing integers with pointers. Please show a [reprex].

Comment: @wildplasser Aside: "comparing an integer to a pointer (constant) here." --> Perhaps.  `NULL` may be 0 of some integer type.  Still _looks_ wrong.

Comment: It still is nonsensense. Types do exist. Comparing different typed values may not always make sense. (IMHO: never, except when coeriable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array format is usually a breadth-first order of the values in a tree, where `null` is a place holder for where there is no node.

So for instance `[1, 1]` is a representation of this tree:

```
      1
     /
    1
```

And `[1, null, 1]` is a representation of this tree:

```
       1
      / \
   null  1
```

Which is:

```
       1 
        \
         1
```

Another, larger example: `[10, 5, 8, 2, null, 6, null, 1, 3, null, 7]` represents:

```
           10
          /  \
         5    8
        /    /
       2    6
      / \    \
     1   3    7
```

So, yes, there is a difference between `[1, 1]` and `[1, null, 1]`.

The reason why your code does not consider the second one valid, is because of the comparison made in this line:

```c
if((max!= NULL && max<=root->val) || (min!= NULL && min>root->val))
//                   ^^
```

You should allow a value to be *equal* to `max`, so correct as follows:

```c
if((max!= NULL && max< root->val) || (min!= NULL && min>root->val))
```

Some other remarks:

- I find it confusing that your function first takes the `max` argument and then the `min`. Consider changing the order of these two parameters.
- Using `NULL` as initial value for `min` and `max` may lead to problems when your tree happens to have a value that is equal to `NULL` (in most environments 0 would be equal `NULL`). Consider using `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` respectively as initial values, and then you can also remove the extra conditions in your `isBST` function.